# Post event on page load when everything is settled

Tags: javascript, jquery

OK, there's a weird problem with a page I have.

When the page first loads, the `div`s I don't want to see are hidden. But seconds later, the `div`s are turned back on again.  When I click on a link for the main page, the `div`s I don't want to see, are hidden, finally.

I want to write a script, like a `POST` event in old PowerBuilder where when everything is said and done, the `div`s I don't want to see, finally get hidden.

I have 1000's of lines of code and searching is painstakingly slow.

I simply need an event that makes sure that the `div`s I don't want to see, stay hidden.

Here's the code:

```
function hideChildDivs(parent) {
    parent.children('div').removeClass('shown').addClass('hidden');
}

function changePage(id, pageName, title, icon) {
    switch (pageName) {
    case 'treeview':
        hideChildDivs($("#otherPageContent"));
        showOnlyActivatedPanel('none');
        $('#otherPageContent').removeClass('shown').addClass('hidden'); //<!-- This is the container wrapper... see below. -->
        $("#pgCoreSettingsMaintenance").removeClass('shown').addClass('hidden'); //<!-- This element needs to remain hidden when the dashboard shows -->
        $("#contentDivWrapper").removeClass("hidden").addClass("shown");
        $("#dash").removeClass();
        $("#tree").removeClass();
        $("#thres").removeClass();
        $('#mainContentPane h1 > i').removeClass().addClass(icon);
        $("#pgDashboard").addClass("hidden").removeClass("shown");
        $('#headerTitleTree').html(title);
        $("#headerTitleRow").removeClass('hidden');
        $("#headerTitleRow").addClass('shown');
        $("#" + id).addClass("active");
        $("#dash").removeClass("active");
        $("#thres").removeClass("active");

        break;

    case 'dashboard':  //<!-- this is the first div that is displayed on startup -->
        hideChildDivs($("#otherPageContent"));
        showOnlyActivatedPanel('none');
        preLoader = false;
        $("#contentDivWrapper").removeClass("shown").addClass("hidden");
        $('#headerTitleTree').html(title);
        $("#headerTitleRow").removeClass('hidden');
        $("#headerTitleRow").addClass('shown');
        $("#dash").removeClass();
        $("#tree").removeClass();
        $("#thres").removeClass();
        $("#pgDashboard").addClass("shown");
        $("#pgDashboard").removeClass("hidden");
        $('#mainContentPane h1 > i').removeClass().addClass(icon);
        $("#" + id).addClass("active");
        $("#tree").removeClass("active");
        $("#thres").removeClass("active");
        $('#otherPageContent').removeClass('hidden').addClass('shown');
        $("#pgDashboard").removeClass('hidden').addClass('shown');
        $("#pgCoreSettingsMaintenance").removeClass('shown').addClass('hidden');
        loadPageIntoDiv("web-resources/templates/" + pageName + ".html");
        getKPIs(myUrl, myCallback);

        break;

    case 'threshold':
        hideChildDivs($("#otherPageContent"));
        showOnlyActivatedPanel('none');
        $('#mainContentPane h1 > i').removeClass().addClass(icon);
        $("#contentDivWrapper").removeClass("shown").addClass("hidden");
        $('#headerTitleTree').html(title);
        $("#headerTitleRow").removeClass('hidden');
        $("#headerTitleRow").addClass('shown');
        $("#" + id).addClass("active");
        $("#tree").removeClass("active");
        $("#dash").removeClass("active");
        $("#pgDashboard").removeClass("shown").addClass("hidden");
        $('#otherPageContent').removeClass('hidden').addClass('shown');
        $("#pgCoreSettingsMaintenance").removeClass('hidden').addClass('shown'); //<!-- this element needs to remain hidden when the dashboard shows. -->
        break;

    }
}
```

here are the divs in order...

```
    <div id="otherPageContent" class="hidden">
      <div id="pgDashboard" class="hidden"></div>
      <div id="pgThresholdConfigurationPH" class="hidden"></div>
      <div id="pgCoreSettingsMaintenancePagePH" class="hidden"></div>
    </div>
```

Comment: You should maybe post the sections of code that relate to the divs that you are hiding and showing, so that people can help you.

Comment: WHY are you randomly CAPITILISING some WORDS and leaving others SMALL? See how strange that looks?

Comment: @Tim, may be he is trying to emphasize on these words ;-)

Comment: Sorry, I'm not yelling... making emphasis... I'll fix and post code.

Comment: Tim you misspelled the word 'capitalize' with an "S" vice the "Z". If we're being critical and yes, anand4Tech you're correct. It was emphasis

Comment: @Peter 'capitalise' is in my dictionary. Some words have more than one spelling. I am using the traditional rule because it has a Latin origin. I knew what your intention was; I was trying to humorously point out that you should be using the markdown formatting.

Comment: Is your script inside a `$(document).ready(function(){})` block? If not, then do so as this should then fire the code once the DOM is ready i.e. all the DIVs and elements are available to work with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `setInterval()` on body onload. It may help you to get some time interval after the page loading.

Preferably you should use `setTimeout()`. It will call your function once, where you can hide ur divs by giving a time interval.

Comment: why not setTimeout() ?

Comment: Yes, setTimeout() will be good. Rather than calling the function again  and agin by setInterval we should call it once

Answer (score 1):

Did you try using the `.ready()` function ?

http://api.jquery.com/ready/

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
  changePage('','dashboard','','');
});
```

It also seems to me that if you need to have a timer waiting for your javascript to finish running in order to set your html back to how you want it, then the order in which your code runs on start isn't right. maybe have a rethink and re-order so that after the initial load your html elements are in the correct state.

Answer (score 0):

Why not give the DIV tags a class attribute and then apply a CSS style of `{display:none;}`?

Comment: .hidden and .shown are the class attributes that I made for that very purpose... thanks for the comment.